# Pen Test advising clearing of fsCachedData

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We have had a Penetration Test of our Xamarin iOS and Android mobile app by an external company.

One of the issues it highlighted was that in iOS there are cached responses in the fsCachedData folders e.g.

var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{GUID}/Library/Caches/{ourappname}/fsCachedData/C3EC741B-8A04-43E2-8EC9-F67CBD37F7F1

We are not explicitly populating this folder and I do not see much discussion anywhere about clearing it up.

Should we be clearing this folder on startup?